# Trouble adding multiple dict k:v pairs

Tags: python, dictionary

I'm not understanding how the k:v coding works. I've read that k:v pairs the items. k is the key and v is the item. If I want an additional field called 'cusip' in addition to 'lastPrice', how would I add that?  Thanks

```
response_dict = response.json()
new_dict = {k: v['lastPrice'] for k, v in response_dict.items()}
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(new_dict, orient='index', columns=['lastPrice'])
```

Comment: Can you provide an example of the `new_dict` value you want to create?

Comment: (e.g. 037833100 for Apple)

Comment: That's not a `dict` value; that's a vague description of the information you want to use to construct the `dict` value.

Comment: If I write `print(new_dict)`, what will I see, *exactly*? Chose whatever minimal example of `response_dict` you want for the purposes of this exercise.

Comment: This is what you see for print(new_dict)    {'AAPL': 151.28, 'MSFT': 265.76,}  I now want to add the Cusip#   {'AAPL': 151.28, 037833100)

Comment: That's what I would see *now*; what is it I *want* to see, i.e., where should 037833100 for Apple appear?

Comment: (Or is that only something that should appear in the data frame? Please provide a [mcve] of what you are trying to accomplish.)

Comment: I now want to add the Cusip# {'AAPL': 151.28, 037833100)  The response_dict = response.json() gives me 50 columns but I just trying to pull out lastPrice and cusip.

Comment: You mean something like `{'AAPL': (151.28, '037833100'), 'MSFT': (265.76, '0134729854')}`? The value should be a tuple constructed from `v`, not just a single value extracted from `v`.

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm trying to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to build the appropriate tuple.

```
new_dict = {k: (v['lastPrice'], v['cusIP']) for k, v in response_dict.items()}
```

In a dictionary comprehension `{key_expr: value_expr for ...}`, both `key_expr` and `value_expr` are allowed to be arbitrary expressions.

Answer (score -1):

Your question is vague, but I would like simulate it maybe useful or close to your issue solution:
Instead of response I defined a new dict with initial values.

```
import pandas as pd
response_dict = {"price":[10,5,9],"Products":["shoes","clothes","hat"], "lastprices":[5,6,7]}
new_dict = {k: v for k, v in response_dict.items()}
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(new_dict)
df
```

If you keen to add new key with new values just try to modify dictioner: for instance

```
new_dict["cusip"]=[1,2,3]
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(new_dict)
df
```